# DataBinding list view

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
Dim  _tableBackLogs As System.Data.DataTable  



 Do While i - 2 > 0
        _tableBackLogs = Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester='" & i - 2 & "'")
        i = i - 2
    Loop

lvBackSubjects.DataSource = _tableBackLogs
lvBackSubjects.DataBind()
```

Doing this binds only the data with the last value of `i` supplied to the `ListView`.I want all the data.Suppose `i=5` . So i want the `ListView` to have data for `i=3,1`.Hope i am not confusing you guys.

Comment: Kindly reply..i urgently need this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the loop is overwriting the variable _tableBackLogs.  Probably better off doing something like this:

```
dim semesters as New System.Text.StringBuilder()

Do While i - 2 > 0
    semesters.Append("'" & i & "',")
    i = i - 2
Loop

' remove the last ,
semesters.Remove(semesters.Length -1,1)

_tableBackLogs = Global.DataAccess.GetDataTable("SELECT SubjectID,SubjectName,Grade FROM SubjectPI WHERE RegNo='" & CInt(HttpContext.Current.Session("userName")) & "' AND Status='Fail' AND Semester in (" & semesters.ToString() & ")"
```